# C: Recurrsive funcation calling with a negative sign

Tags: c, recursion

What's the result of a function being called with a negative sign in the front?  Is it to turn the return value into negative?

```
int someFunction(int newBoard[9], int aValue) {

    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if(newBoard[i] == 0) {
            newBoard[i] = player;
            int thisScore = -someFunction(newBoard, aValue*-1); 
            // why this function being called with a negative sign?   Is to turn the return value into negative?
        }
    }
  return someValue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct, since someFunction returns an integer putting a '-' in front negates the result

```
e.g. int n = 1;
     printf( "%d", -n );
     ...
     -1
```

how this is used in your context is more difficult to guess since you do not provide much context in your question.

Answer (score 1):

ya... Return value is stored as `-`ve value in variable `thisScore`..

Try this code...It may clear your doubt

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int fun(void)
  {
   return 20;
  }

  main()
  {
    int a=- fun();
    printf("%d\n",a);
  }
```